# Refer assemblies(artifacts) from artifactory in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, artifactory, devops

I'm trying to make my .Net project work with Artifactory. So far I've uploaded the reference assemblies(.dll) files to artifactory using Jenkins. Now to build my solution, I want to refer those uploaded reference assemblies(artifacts) from artifactory, rather than referring them from the local path.
I tried using the MSBuild artifactory plugin, but it has a partial support for Jenkins.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not reference dll directly from Artifactory. To use them as dependencies in your project you have two options :

- first one is to download them locally before your build (you can
  setup a prebuild step for that)
- second one is to create a nuget
  package containing these dlls, to upload this nuget package to
  Artifactory (this is where the MsBuild Artifactory plugin can help
  you) and use it as a nuget dependency within your project where the
  nuget feed used by Visual Studio will be configured to reach
  Artifactory nuget repository.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would the second option work with jenkins?
I tried it, but its not giving me the desired result.

Comment: Yes the MsBuild Artifactory pluin works jenkins or any CI server that allows to run MsBuild.